# Bind CUDA Texture to a float Image

Tags: cuda, textures

I have a 1 channel, float image in C side like the following:

```
int width, height;
float* img;
```

I want to pass this image to a CUDA texture. I'm reading the [NVIDIA CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf) (page 42-43) and using the tutorial, wrote a code like the following:

> **main.cpp:**

```
int main()
{
     int width, height;
     float* h_Input;
     ReadImage(&h_Input, &width, &height); // My function which reads the image.
     WriteImage(h_Input, width, height); // works perfectly...

     float* h_Output = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float) * width * height);

     CalculateWithCuda(h_Input, h_Output, width,height);
     WriteImage(h_Output, width, height); // writes an empty-gray colored image.... *WHY???* 
}
```

> **kernel.cu:**

```
texture<float, cudaTextureType2D, cudaReadModeElementType> texRef; // 2D float texture

__global__ void Kernel(float* output, int width, int height)
{
    int i = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; // row number 
    int j = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; // col number

    if(i < height && j < width)
    {
           float temp = tex2D(texRef, i + 0.5f, j + 0.5f);
           output[i * width + j] = temp ;
    }
} 

void CalculateWithCuda(const float* h_input, float* h_output, int width, int height)
{
    float* d_output;

    // Allocate CUDA array in device memory
    cudaChannelFormatDesc channelDesc = cudaCreateChannelDesc(32, 0, 0, 0,cudaChannelFormatKindFloat);
    cudaArray* cuArray;
    cudaMallocArray(&cuArray, &channelDesc, width, height);
    // Copy to device memory some data located at address h_data in host memory 
    cudaMemcpyToArray(cuArray, 0, 0, h_input, width * height * sizeof(float) , cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    // Set texture parameters
    texRef.addressMode[0] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    texRef.addressMode[1] = cudaAddressModeWrap;
    texRef.filterMode     = cudaFilterModeLinear;
    texRef.normalized     = true;

    // Bind the array to the texture reference
    cudaBindTextureToArray(texRef, cuArray, channelDesc);

    // Allocate GPU buffers for the output image ..
    cudaMalloc(&d_output, sizeof(float) * width * height);

    dim3 threadsPerBlock(16,16);
    dim3 numBlocks((width/threadsPerBlock.x) + 1, (height/threadsPerBlock.y) + 1);

    Kernel<<<numBlocks, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_output, width,height);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    // Copy output vector from GPU buffer to host memory.
    cudaMemcpy(h_output, d_output, sizeof(float) * width * height, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    // Free GPU  memory ...
}
```

As I said in the code; this Kernel has to read from the texture and give me the same image as output. However, I'm taking an empty (grays colored) image for the output. I just implemented the same way in the tutorial, why does not this texture work?

I will be appreciated if somebody show me a way to fix this issue ...

> PS: Sure, it's not the all of the code. I just copied the necessary parts. If you need other details, I will support as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For clarity, the Programming Guide does not include any checking of the return values of the calls in its examples. I'm not sure I agree with that decision as checking the return values really should be ingrained in every CUDA programmer. Please take a look at the SDK examples for how to check the return values of each and every one of your CUDA calls (including the kernel call), and let us know if that helped you resolve the issue.

Comment: @RogerDahl: Actually, I already do it... You mean using `cudaStatus`, right? I don't have any error messages. Everyting seems fine. However, the code doesn't produce the image that I'm waiting for ...

Comment: The problem was with the `texRef.normalized = true;` line. I removed it, and it's working fine, don't know why ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the normalized coordinates the texture is accessed via the coordinates from 0 to 1 (exclusive). You forgot translate your integer threadIdx-based coordinates into normalized.

```
unsigned int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
unsigned int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y; 
float u = x / (float)width;  
float v = y / (float)height;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'd fix the grammar in this, but SO won't let me. (Hint, hint :) )